# Excel for travel expenses

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Every Month I need to make an excel sheet with travel expenses, since this is a tedious task I decided to make a little python script to do this work for me.

Everything works correctly, but any comments regarding style and functionality are welcome.

```
import datetime
import calendar
import re

import argparse
import openpyxl

END_OF_WEEK = 5

def get_working_days(date, exclude_days):
    """
    Gets the working days of that month

    args:
        date (str): The date in MM_YYYY format
        exclude (set): A set of excluded weekday(s)

    returns: 
        a List of weekday dates in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format
    """
    month, year = map(int, date.split('_'))
    num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    for day in range(1, num_days+1):
        date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        if date.weekday() < END_OF_WEEK and date.weekday() not in exclude_days:
            yield date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

def travel_expenses(date, home, work, company, distance, price, exclude_days):
    """
    Creates Excel documents for travel expenses

    args:
        date (str): The month/year to create travel expenses for
        home (str): The home Address
        work (str): The work address
        company (str): The name of the company/customer currently traveling to
        distance (float): The distance in Km
        price (float): The price in $currency$
        exclude (list): A list of excluded weekdays

    returns: 
        None
    """

    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.title = date

    optional = ['Prijs'] if price else ['Afstand (km)'] if distance else []
    headers = ['Datum', 'Adres van vertrek', 'Adres van aankomst', 'Klant'] + optional
    for i, head in enumerate(headers, 1):
        worksheet.cell(row=1, column=i, value=head)

    exclude_days = set() if exclude_days is None else set(map(int, exclude_days))
    days = list(get_working_days(date, exclude_days))

    for i, day in enumerate(days, 2):
        for j, col in enumerate(filter(None, [day, home, work, company, distance, price]), 1):
            worksheet.cell(row=i, column=j, value=col)

    # Add sum of distance or price if exists
    total = None
    if not price is None:
        total = price * len(days)

    if not distance is None:
        total = distance * len(days)

    if not total is None:
        worksheet.cell(row=2 + len(days), column=4, value='Total:')
        worksheet.cell(row=2 + len(days), column=5, value=total)

    workbook.save("{}.xlsx".format(date))

def parse_arguments():
    """Arguments parser."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [options] <date> <home> <work> <company>',
                                     description='Declaring Travel expenses, by @Ludisposed',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     epilog='''
Examples:
  python reiskosten.py 06_2018 "111AA, 2" "2222BB, 1" "Company Name"
  python reiskosten.py 06_2018 "111AA, 2" "2222BB, 1" "Company Name" --distance 103.2
  python reiskosten.py 06_2018 "111AA, 2" "2222BB, 1" "Company Name" --price 20.1
  python reiskosten.py 06_2018 "111AA, 2" "2222BB, 1" "Company Name" --exclude 01
  python reiskosten.py 06_2018 "111AA, 2" "2222BB, 1" "Company Name" --price 10.5 --exclude 23
''')

    parser.add_argument('date', type=str, help='The date in MM_YYYY format')
    parser.add_argument('home', type=str, help='The Home address in "PostalCode, Number+Appendix" format')
    parser.add_argument('work', type=str, help='The Work address in "PostalCode, Number+Appendix" format')
    parser.add_argument('company', type=str, help='The company name')
    parser.add_argument('--distance', type=float, help='The distance of the travel (Useful for travels with Car)')
    parser.add_argument('--price', type=float, help='The price of the travel (Useful for travels with Train)')
    parser.add_argument('--exclude', type=list, help='Exclude some days in 02 format (Meaning excluding Monday and Wednesday)')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.price is None and not args.distance is None:
        parser.error("Specify Price or Distance not both")

    if not re.match(r"(\d{1,2}_\d{4})", args.date):
        parser.error("Date should be in {MM_YYYY} format")

    addres_regex = re.compile(r"(\d{4} [A-Z]{2}, \d+[A-Z]{0,1})")
    if not re.match(addres_regex, args.home):
        parser.error("Home address should be in {1111 AA, 2A} or {1111 AA, 2} format")

    if not re.match(addres_regex, args.work):
        parser.error("Work address should be in {1111 AA, 2A} or {1111 AA, 2} format")

    return args.date, args.home, args.work, args.company, args.distance, args.price, args.exclude

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_arguments()
    travel_expenses(*args)
```